# getting error of Name or service not known while consuming spring services

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a service using **springboot**, where I am using okhttp3 and consuming a http url.
So here is the scenario : when I am running the service in localhost using (http://localhost:8080/myservicename) it is giving me expected response. but when I am trying to run the service using https://myservice.com/myservicename then I am getting Name or service not known error.

Comment: can you elaborate more? why are you using that URL?

Comment: because that URL returns the expected output and the URL is not secure. It is just a private URL. It is normal http URL so when i using normal http://localhost call then i am getting output. but when i change it to secure https it is throwing me error of Name  or service not know. How i can bypass this check or how to avoid this.